# How would be the query for this XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm having a hard time trying to create the query. This is the file:

```
<Root>
<Summary>
    <Objective ID="1">
        <Exam Result="70" />
        <Exam Result="90" />
    </Objective>
    <Objective ID="2">
        <Exam Result="100" />
        <Exam Result="90" />
    </Objective>
</Summary>
</Root>
```

I need to get the values in List< List< double>>. The first list if for objectives, and the last one is to store each result.

Any doubt, please let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("Objective")
                 .Select(x => x.Elements("Exam")
                               .Select(exam => (double) exam.Attribute("Result"))
                               .ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Or if the objective ID is important, you might want to consider a `Dictionary<int, List<double>>`:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("Objective")
                 .ToDictionary(x => (int) x.Attribute("ID"),
                               x => x.Elements("Exam")
                                     .Select(y => (double) y.Attribute("Result"))
                                     .ToList());
```

Or a `Lookup<int, double>`:

```
var results = doc.Descendants("Exam")
                 .ToLookup(x => (int) x.Parent.Attribute("ID"),
                           x => x.Select(y => (double) y.Attribute("Result"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a ',' rather than a '.' at the end of your .ToDictionary line?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid: Yup - just a typo :)

Comment: @PhilippSchmid: In future, do go ahead - just leave a comment so I notice and can check :)

Comment: @Jon This is great. This is the the last question. How can I get a result grades? I mean, have a list ( List ) where contains the values of X objective.

For example, if X = 1, it must get a list of results from objective 1. It would be contain, 70 and 80.

Comment: @OscarFimbres: With the dictionary version, you'd just use `List<double> foo = results[1];`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I took the liberty to correct a minor typo (Exame => Exam)